# What is the program doing ? cplusplus

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void updateValue(int *p){
    *p = 610 % 255;
}

int main(){
    char ch = 'A';
    updateValue((int*)&ch);
    cout << ch;
}
```

Dear Friends why output is d ?
please explain updateValue((int*)&ch) line means?

Comment: It does something *bad* that you shouldn't be doing. It leads to *undefined behavior*. As a general rule, whenever you seem to need a C-style cast (like `(int*)` is) then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It leads to undefined behavior, but in this specific case, it returns character 'd' because the result of 610 mod 255 is 100, which corresponds to character 'd' in ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `int` at the memory pointed to by `&ch`. Pretending that there is one and assigning an `int` after dereferencing the pointer leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). In a nutshell, ub means that the standard does not define what the behavior of the resuling program should be. A compiler that conforms with the C++ standard could generate a program that prints `"foobar"` on the screen from your code.

Answer (score -1):

Here we are typecasting a char variable in the int format
the line

#### updateValue((int*)&ch);

shows that the typecasting is explicit as int*p = (int*)&ch

p is  also having the address of ch

so *p will point towards the value of ch and try to read the 4 bits as

it will read it as an integer so it will read 65+ garbage value

and when *p =610%255

the remainder of the above equation will be 100

*p-value is now reassigned to 100

When we print the ch it will convert it into ASCII value form

Then it will print the value corresponding to 100

that is 'd'